Wrong index usage in LEFT JOINs ( gist index instead of dedicated index)
In Postgres 16 I have noticed the following "wrong" index usage behavior:
I have a table (350000 records) with a composite primary key:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.mytable
(
    arflgart integer NOT NULL,
    arkeyart character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT pk_mytable PRIMARY KEY (arflgart, arkeyart),
    ... 

There is also a BTREE index idx_keyart_flgart on (arkeyart,arflgart) and a gist index
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_arkeyart ON public.mytable 
USING gist (arkeyart COLLATE pg_catalog."default" gist_trgm_ops);

When I made queries on another table with a LEFT JOIN to mytable on the two primary keys:
SELECT *
FROM another_table tab2
LEFT JOIN mytable ON tab2.field1=arflgart AND tab2.field2 = arkeyart
WHERE tab2.field3 > 0

The query execution takes ages because it DOESN'T use the primary key index or the idx_keyart_flgart, but uses the gist index idx_arkeyart ?!?
...
Index Scan using idx_arkeyart on mytable
Index Cond: ((arkeyart)::text = (another_table.field2)::text)
Filter: (arflgart = another_table.field1)
Buffers: shared hit=14,224,232
...

If I drop the gist index the query is immediate.
*** Why Postgres fails  to recognize the correct index to use?
This is the complete execution plan:
"Gather  (cost=1000.71..36112.85 rows=59828 width=56) (actual time=6.490..34806.715 rows=60758 loops=1)"
"  Workers mytable: 3"
"  Workers Launched: 3"
"  Buffers: shared hit=14416778"
"  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.71..29130.05 rows=19299 width=56) (actual time=9.918..34723.521 rows=15190 loops=4)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=14416778"
"        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.42..22483.10 rows=19299 width=49) (actual time=0.408..236.928 rows=15190 loops=4)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=192546"
"              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on ba_salart001 ba_salart  (cost=0.00..12263.89 rows=19299 width=49) (actual time=0.029..80.870 rows=15190 loops=4)"
"                    Filter: (saqtagia <> '0'::numeric)"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 108773"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=10258"
"              ->  Index Only Scan using pk_another_table001 on another_table001 another_table  (cost=0.42..0.53 rows=1 width=26) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=60758)"
"                    Index Cond: ((ulcodkey = (ba_salart.saunilog)::text) AND (field1 = ba_salart.saflgart) AND (field2 = (ba_salart.sakeyart)::text))"
"                    Heap Fetches: 7"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=182288"
"        ->  Index Scan using idx_arkeyart on mytable001 mytable  (cost=0.28..0.33 rows=1 width=22) (actual time=2.268..2.268 rows=1 loops=60758)"
"              Index Cond: ((arkeyart)::text = (another_table.field2)::text)"
"              Filter: (arflgart = another_table.field1)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=14224232"
"Planning:"
"  Buffers: shared hit=890"
"Planning Time: 14.776 ms"
"Execution Time: 34813.134 ms"


Please share the complete EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) output.

@LaurenzAlbe: done

Thanks. PostgreSQL probably prefers the GiST index because it is smaller. I have no good idea how to fix the problem.

@LaurenzAlbe: using the "natural" index (primary key) the query duration is 1.5 sec, with the gist index is 34 secs (and we also have another table similar to  mytable 

same combined primary key - that has the same issue)


What is your current setting for cpu_operator_cost and what happens when you increase this cost? And what about random_page_cost compared to seq_page_cost ?

@FrankHeikens: cpu_operator_cost = 0.0025 (default) ; random_page_cost = 1.1 ; ( probably set using pgtune) ; seq_page_cost = 1.0 (default)

What happens to the query plan when you change (for testing) the cpu_operator_cost to something like 0.05 ? Just for your database session, you can use SET cpu_operator_cost  TO 0.05; and then execute the explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for your SQL statement.

@FrankHeikens: thanks for the hint; the problem was in the production environment and we dropped the gist indexes; so I must prepare a test environment to try what you suggested, I'll let you know when I'll make the test!

Planning for GiST indexes is generally kind of crappy.  Because they are so extensible, the planner doesn't have much insight into what goes on inside them to do better planning (although I'm sure it could still be improved somewhat, either generically or specifically for gist_trgm_ops, with enough effort).  This generally isn't a huge problem as usually you don't have a GiST index plus other indexes at the same time, which both support the same operators.
Because the index scan is only expected to return one row and because no rows are removed by the filter, that means there is little point in using a multi-column index when a single-column index is already selective enough to get to one row.  So because there is no point in using a multicolumn index to get unneeded selectivity, and because GiST planning is kind of crappy, it decides to use the single-column GiST index.
The ability to use gist_trgm_ops to support equality was not added to pg_trgm until version '1.6'.  I had some misgivings about doing this at the time just for this reason--it does in fact support equality, but in an inferior way, so declaring the support might pose an attractive nuisance to the planner.
You could drop the pg_trgm extension (cascading to dropping the supporting index), then recreate it with create extension pg_trgm version '1.5';.  Then rebuild the indexes, and they will no longer be used for equality queries. Note that the change from 1.5 to 1.6 did nothing but add these equality operators, so reverting that should do you no harm.  However, a dump will not memorialize which version was in use, so restoring from a dump would go back to using the newest available version and so create the problem again.
Alternatively, you could execute alter operator family  gist_trgm_ops USING gist drop operator 11 (text, text); but I think this presents dump/restore and pg_upgrade hazards as well.

Thanks, we ended up dropping the gist index and redesigning other queries that "somewhat" used it.
